# Main php function used to call other functions with arguments

Tags: php, wordpress

What Iam trying to create if possible within WordPress or via just php is that i have functions such as below.

```
function myfunction_displays_something_one() {

echo "string";
echo "string"; }

function myfunction_displays_something_two() {

echo "string";
echo "string";

}

function myfunction_displays_something_three( $arg1, $arg2 ) {

echo "<p>";
echo $arg1 $arg2;
echo "/<p>";

}
```

I would like the functions above to be called and displayed via

```
function myfunction_displays( $display ) {

    if ( $display == 'something-one' )
    return myfunction_displays_something_two();

    if ( $display == 'soemthing-two' )
    return myfunction_displays_something_two();

}
```

when called vai the php file would like to call the three functions above like so

```
<?php myfunction_displays( something-two ); ?>
<?php myfunction_displays( something-three ); ?>
```

i have been able to make the first two work because they have no arguments but I am unable to call the third function because it has arguments.

Is there a way to create this maybe using Wordpress Filters or just php ?

Comment: You can make a [Class](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: Sure, but why do you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply is there any example out there that you can share so that i can guide myself?

Comment: Did you try invoking the method by passing the arguments as strings (by using the "")?

Comment: @user574632 The reason i want to do this is because I would like everything to be handled under one function for example if create a function called myfunction_displays_something_really_big I would prefer to just call it via myfunction_displays('big') for example

Answer (score 0):

Online DEMO : https://eval.in/87273

```
function myfunction_displays( $display ,$arrArg = array()) {

        if ( $display == 'something-one' )
        return myfunction_displays_something_two();

        if ( $display == 'soemthing-two' )
        return myfunction_displays_something_two();

        if ( $display == 'soemthing-three' )
       {
          $a1 = isset($arrArg[0]) ? $arrArg[0] : ""; 
          $a2 = isset($arrArg[1]) ? $arrArg[1] : "";
           return  myfunction_displays_something_three($a1,$a2);
       }

    }
```

And call it like this:

```
<?php myfunction_displays( 'something-two' ); ?>
<?php myfunction_displays( 'something-three',array(0=>'value1',1=>'value2')); ?>
```

Comment: @user3174600 : did you try this?

Comment: @AwladLiton Thanks tired it and it outputted the as i needed it to. Is there a way to achieve the same results within WordPress without using the if statements and isset.

Comment: i don't know much about wordpress. But it is raw php code it should work in wordpress too. Did you try this in wordpress? what error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way:

```
function myfunction_displays( $display, $arg1=NULL, $arg2=NULL ) {

    if ( $display == 'something-one' )
    return myfunction_displays_something_two();

    if ( $display == 'something-two' )
    return myfunction_displays_something_two();

    if ( $display == 'something-three' )
    return myfunction_displays_something_three($arg1, $arg2);

}
```

The "=NULL" part means you don't have to fill them in every time you call it.

An example:

```
<?php myfunction_displays( 'something-two' ); ?>
<?php myfunction_displays( 'something-three', 'value1', 'value2' ); ?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't using call_user_func() or call_user_func_array() be a lot cleaner and easier?

Comment: @Mark Baker call_user_func() was difficult for me to understand when I was a beginner, so I didn't offer it.